# UICollectionView indexPath.row strange behaviour

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, nsindexpath

I'm having strange issue while scrolling one of my collectionViews. When I'm printing `indexPath.row` is goes ok from 0..6 but then last `indexPath.row` is 3, and then if I scroll back it either crashes with excbadadress or prints 1, 2, 4 in random order. I assume that I have and error in my code but really don't understand where is it.
Here is my code:
VC:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if collectionView == mainEventsCollectionView {
        return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 40, height: 180)
    } else {
        return CGSize(width: 150, height: 200)
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if collectionView == mainEventsCollectionView {
        return 3
    } else {
        return 7
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if collectionView == mainEventsCollectionView {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "mainEventsCell", for: indexPath) as! MainEventCollectionViewCell
        cell.eventTitle.text = "Hello world".uppercased()
        cell.setupCell()
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "importantEventsCell", for: indexPath) as! ImportantEventsCollectionViewCell
        print(indexPath.row)
        cell.setupCell()
        return cell
    }
}
```

Cell:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.roundCorners(.allCorners, radius: 6, borderColor: .clear, borderWidth: 0)
}

func setupCell() {
    self.content.backgroundColor = colorWithAlpha(.black, alpha: 0.7)
    self.eventDate.textColor = .white
    self.eventTime.textColor = .white
    self.eventName.textColor = .white
    if self.content.layer.sublayers!.count > 3 {
        self.content.layer.sublayers!.removeLast()
    }
    if self.eventDate.text == "Today" {
        self.content.backgroundColor = .clear
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.content.drawGradient(colors: [UIColor(red: 250/255, green: 217/255, blue: 97/255, alpha: 0.7).cgColor, UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 135/255, blue: 67/255, alpha: 0.7).cgColor], locations: [0, 1])
        })
        self.eventDate.textColor = .black
        self.eventTime.textColor = .black
        self.eventName.textColor = .black
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see anything that would cause this, is this on github?

Comment: Is scrolling crashing for  mainEventsCell or importantEventsCell?

Comment: no it is not , and importantEventsCell, should also add that these collectionViews are in header of tableView but dataSource and delegate to ViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was that I've tried to apply gradient to a `UIView`, which had elements (`UILables`). What I had to do is add a subview to the `UIView` and apply gradient to it.